# How to change the position of toast message in vue-toasted?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-toasted

I use [vue-toasted](https://github.com/shakee93/vue-toasted). I registered `vue-toasted` in `main.js` and use it as below:

```
import Toasted from 'vue-toasted'

Vue.use(Toasted, Option)
```

And use it like this in a vue component

```
this.$toasted.error("Temperature too Hot").goAway(5000),
```

But I do not know how to change the position of toasted message. The current position is `'top-right'`. How do I change this?

Comment: Questions are generally best received on SO when an individual shows that they are also working hard to solve their own problem. Part of the way to show that is to take a few seconds to properly format and proofread your questions. I'd suggest checking out [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the demo [here](https://shakee93.github.io/vue-toasted/)

```
let toast = this.$toasted.show("Toasted !!", { 
     theme: "toasted-primary", 
     position: "top-right", 
     duration : 5000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By just following the link you provided, it is apparent that you can change the position with the Container Position setting.

[image: Container Position]

Also you can set the position according to the API page.

> API Options below are the options you can pass to create a toast
>
> Position   String  'top-right' Position
>   of the toast container  ['top-right', 'top-center', 'top-left',
>   'bottom-right', 'bottom-center', 'bottom-left']

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to change the position of toasted msg.

This is the way that I found

if you want to use Options inside error or show method, you do not put option value in Vue.use().

After removing option in Vue.use, I can move msg

I hope it will be helpful to you guys

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually set the options in your main.js

```
import Toasted from 'vue-toasted';
const toastOptions = {
    position: 'top-center',
    duration : 2000,
    theme: "toasted-primary"
}
Vue.use(Toasted, toastOptions);
```